# how to implement bottomsheetdialogfragment

Tags: java, android, fragment

There is a holder

```
public class ClientTivarHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

    public TextView texttovarname,texttovarprice;

    public RoundedImageView imageTovar;

    public CardView cardTovar;

    public ItemClickListener itemClickListener;

    private Dialog dialog;

    private Context context;

    public ClientTivarHolder(View itemView){

        super(itemView);

        texttovarname=itemView.findViewById(R.id.texttovrnme);

        texttovarprice=itemView.findViewById(R.id.pricetexttovar);

        imageTovar=itemView.findViewById(R.id.tovarImage);

        cardTovar=itemView.findViewById(R.id.tovarcard);

    }

    public void setItemClickListner(ItemClickListener listner){this.itemClickListener=listner;}

    @Override

    public void onClick(View view){

        itemClickListener.onClick(view,getAdapterPosition(),false);

    }

}
```

There is an adapter

```
public class TovarsAdapter {

    private String TovarName,TovarOpisanie,TovarPrice,TovarImage,ShopPhone,ShopUid;

    public TovarsAdapter(){

    }

    public TovarsAdapter(String tovarName, String tovarOpisanie, String tovarPrice, String tovarImage, String shopPhone, String shopUid) {

       this. TovarName = tovarName;

      this.  TovarOpisanie = tovarOpisanie;

      this.  TovarPrice = tovarPrice;

      this.  TovarImage = tovarImage;

       this. ShopPhone = shopPhone;

     this.   ShopUid = shopUid;

    }

    public String getTovarName() {

        return TovarName;

    }

    public void setTovarName(String tovarName) {

        TovarName = tovarName;

    }

    public String getTovarOpisanie() {

        return TovarOpisanie;

    }

    public void setTovarOpisanie(String tovarOpisanie) {

        TovarOpisanie = tovarOpisanie;

    }

    public String getTovarPrice() {

        return TovarPrice;

    }

    public void setTovarPrice(String tovarPrice) {

        TovarPrice = tovarPrice;

    }

    public String getTovarImage() {

        return TovarImage;

    }

    public void setTovarImage(String tovarImage) {

        TovarImage = tovarImage;

    }

    public String getShopPhone() {

        return ShopPhone;

    }

    public void setShopPhone(String shopPhone) {

        ShopPhone = shopPhone;

    }

    public String getShopUid() {

        return ShopUid;

    }

    public void setShopUid(String shopUid) {

        ShopUid = shopUid;

    }

}
```

And the interface class ItemClickListener

```
public interface ItemClickListener {

    void onClick(View view, int position, boolean isLongClick);

}
```

Activate itself where I want to implement it

```
public class TovarActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private DatabaseReference tovars;

private RecyclerView recyclerView;

private String uid,srav;

    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;

    @Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tovar);

        layoutManager=new GridLayoutManager(this,2);

        Log.d("Uid",getIntent().getExtras().get("ShopUid").toString());

        recyclerView=(RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.tovarrec);

        tovars= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Tovars");

        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    }

    @Override

    protected void onStart() {

        super.onStart();

        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<TovarsAdapter> options=new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<TovarsAdapter>()

                .setQuery(tovars.orderByChild("ShopUid").equalTo(getIntent().getExtras().get("ShopUid").toString()),TovarsAdapter.class).build();

        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<TovarsAdapter, ClientTivarHolder> adapter=new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<TovarsAdapter, ClientTivarHolder>(options) {

            @Override

            protected void onBindViewHolder( @androidx.annotation.NonNull ClientTivarHolder holder, int position,  @androidx.annotation.NonNull TovarsAdapter model) {

        holder.texttovarprice.setText(model.getTovarPrice());

        holder.texttovarname.setText(model.getTovarOpisanie());

holder.texttovarname.setHint(model.getShopUid());

                Transformation transformation=new RoundedTransformationBuilder().borderColor(Color.WHITE).borderWidthDp(3).cornerRadius(12).oval(false).build();

                Picasso.get().load(model.getTovarImage()).transform(transformation).into(holder.imageTovar);

            }

            @Override

            public ClientTivarHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

                View view= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_tovars,parent,false);

              ClientTivarHolder holder=new ClientTivarHolder(view);

                return holder;

            }

        };

        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        adapter.startListening();

    }

}
```

Problem: I don’t know how to make a listener on a separate item send a hint from it with a uid to receive certain information in the bottomsheetdialogfragmemt.  I tried to make a fragment manager in the holder but it didn't work out.  How can I solve my problem?

tried to make fragment manager inside holder but didn't work